# React JS - Passing functions for child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an App component and a function 'modalToggled' inside its.
I want to pass the function to multiple child components until I get to the last one, the 'interiores' component.

Like this:

```
<App> -> <Coluna1> -> <MenuPrincipal> -> <Portfolio> -> <PortfolioMenu> -> <interiores>
```

App Component, the parent of all components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Coluna1 from './Coluna1'    

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)       
    this.state = {
      modalOn: false
    }
   this.modalToggled = this.modalToggled.bind(this)
  }      

  modalToggled = (on) => {
    this.setState({modalOn: on});
  }      

  render() {
    return (
      <div>          
          <Coluna1 onModalToggle={this.modalToggled}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the 'Coluna1' the first child component. I did the same thing in the another ones: 'MenuPrincipal', 'Portfolio', 'PortfolioMenu'

```
class Coluna1 extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <MenuPrincipal onModalToggle={this.props.modalToggled} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Coluna1
```

Therefore here is the last component interiores, when I click on the button there appears an error message:

**TypeError: _this.props.onModalToggle is not a function**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'    
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';    


class Interiores extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {              
      open: false
    }      
  }

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
    this.props.onModalToggle(true);
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.onModalToggle(false);
  };   

  render() { 
    const { open } = this.state;   
    return (                  
      <div>
          <button onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>
          <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center></Modal>                    
     </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Interiores;
```

Does anybody know how to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens, because in App class you pass prop with name **onModalToggle**:

```
<Coluna1 onModalToggle={this.modalToggled}/>
```

But in Coluna1 you receive this props with wrong name, **modalToggled**:

```
<MenuPrincipal onModalToggle={this.props.modalToggled} />
```

Just make the names of props equal. In Coluna1 and other intermediate components pass and receive this props as **onModalToggle**:

```
<MenuPrincipal onModalToggle={this.props.onModalToggle} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
modalToggled = (on) => {
    this.setState({modalOn: on});
  }
```

Since this is a class function it needs to be defined like

```
modalToggled(on) {
    this.setState({modalOn: on});
}
```

Comment: Thank you but, now there appears another error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
onOpenModal
C:/Users/claudio/Desktop/maurobitar_2018/src/Interiores.js:17
  14 |  }
  15 | 
  16 |  onOpenModal () {
> 17 |    this.setState({ open: true });
  18 |    this.props.onModalToggle(true);
  19 |  };
  20 | 
View compiled

Comment: The last error message appeard when I change:

onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
    this.props.onModalToggle(true);
  };

to: 

onOpenModal  {
    this.setState({ open: true });
    this.props.onModalToggle(true);
  };

When I only changed the suggested altered line, it still showing the same error message